# Naming intents in Android

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-intent

I want to start an intent through a list.
But I don't want the layout text to be the name of the intent, which it is right now. How do I make it something custom?

This is my try on making it:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
String Names[] = { "1 To 9 Tabels", "10 To 19 Tabels" };
String Classstart[] = {".First, .Second"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <String>(Menu. this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Names));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String Classstart = Names[position];
    try {
        Class ClassNames;
        ClassNames = Class.forName("com.sapphire.android." + Classstart);
        Intent StartIntent = new Intent(Menu. this, ClassNames);
        startActivity(StartIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify this: "but I don't want the layout text to be the name of the intent," I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, it crashes when you click on an item right now, because you are starting the wrong Activity. Try to change it to this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String activity = Classstart[position];
    try {
        Class ClassNames;
        ClassNames = Class.forName("com.sapphire.android." + activity);
        Intent StartIntent = new Intent(Menu. this, ClassNames);
        startActivity(StartIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that I simply take the class name from the Classstart array rather than from the Names array.